# How to use Ghidra modify a PLT Function return a fixed value with automatically execute python scripts?

Tags: ghidra

I'm trying to use python script in Ghidra to let a plt function named as  memcmp return a fix value, But i have no idea for that.
like this:

```
.text:10006E84
.text:10006E88 89 21 00 08                   lbz       r9, 0xB0+var_A8(r1)
.text:10006E8C 2C 09 00 00                   cmpwi     r9, 0
.text:10006E90 41 82 00 88                   beq       loc_10006F18
.text:10006E90
.text:10006E94 38 A0 00 41                   li        r5, 0x41 # 'A'                # n
.text:10006E98 38 81 00 08                   addi      r4, r1, 0xB0+var_A8           # s2
.text:10006E9C 38 61 00 4C                   addi      r3, r1, 0xB0+var_64           # s1
.text:10006EA0 48 00 23 B1                   bl        memcmp
.text:10006EA0
.text:10006EA4 7C 7D 1B 79                   mr.       r29, r3
.text:10006EA8 40 82 01 1C                   bne       loc_10006FC4
.text:10006EA8
.text:10006EAC 38 80 00 04                   li        r4, 4                         # type
```

memcmp as a PLT function:

```
.text:10009250                               # int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
.text:10009250                               memcmp:                                 # CODE XREF: sub_10002264+84↑p
.text:10009250                                                                       # sub_10002264+D4↑p
.text:10009250                                                                       # licd_public_key_hash_check+2F4↑p
.text:10009250 3D 60 10 02                   lis       r11, memcmp_plt@ha
.text:10009254 81 6B 00 C8                   lwz       r11, memcmp_plt@l(r11)        # __imp_memcmp
.text:10009258 7D 69 03 A6                   mtctr     r11
.text:1000925C 4E 80 04 20                   bctr
```

How to use Ghidra python script to do this automatically?